# How can I visualize the overlapping area of 2 masks in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

When i create a mask in Pygame, for example:

```py
self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```

Can i see the result, the grid with Boolean values?

And question 2, can I make an overlap visible when two mask overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i see the result, the grid with Boolean values.

You can only see what you are drawing on the screen. A mask cannot be drawn on the screen so you cannot see it.

> Can I make an overlap visible when two mask overlap?

Create a *Mask* containing the overlapping set bits between 2 *Masks* with [`pygame.mask.Mask.overlap_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap_mask).
Convert the *Mask* to a *Surface* with [`pygame.mask.Mask.to_surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.to_surface). e.g.:

```py
overlap_mask = mask1.overlap_mask(mask2, (offset_x, offset_y))
overlap_surf = overlap_mask.to_surface(setcolor= (255, 0, 0))
overlap_surf.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
```

---

Minimal example:

The overlapping pixels are colored red.

[image]

```py
import pygame, math

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

image1 = pygame.image.load("Banana.png")
image2 = pygame.image.load("Bird.png")
rect1 = image1.get_rect(center = (165, 150))
rect2 = image1.get_rect(center = (135, 150))
mask1 = pygame.mask.from_surface(image1)
mask2 = pygame.mask.from_surface(image2)

angle = 0
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    angle += 0.01
    rect1.centery = 150 + round(60 * math.sin(angle))        

    offset_x = rect2.x - rect1.x
    offset_y = rect2.y - rect1.y
    overlap_mask = mask1.overlap_mask(mask2, (offset_x, offset_y))
    overlap_surf = overlap_mask.to_surface(setcolor = (255, 0, 0))
    overlap_surf.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(image1, rect1)
    window.blit(image2, rect2)
    window.blit(overlap_surf, rect1)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Please, can you explain :  overlap_mask = mask1.overlap_mask(mask2, (offset_x, offset_y))? I don't understand the meaning of offset.

Comment: @Joachim The _Surfaces_ do not have the same position on the screen. There is an offset between the _Surfaces_. The offset it the distance from the top left of `image1`/`rect1` to the top left of `iamge2`/`rect2`. If they are in the same position, the offset is (0, 0).

Comment: That's clear. But what does  offset_x and offset_y mean? For what does overlap_mask need them? That's what i don't understand?t

Comment: @Joachim Read the comment! It is the distance from the top left of `image1`/`rect1` to the top left of `image2`/`rect2`. You only need them if the images are not exactly  overlapping. Look at the animated images in my answer. The have not the same position. The difference is `offset_x = rect2.x - rect1.x` `offset_y = rect2.y - rect1.y`. A _Mask_ and a _Surface_ have no position. A _Surface_ is `blit` at a specified position on the screen.